# how to create a playplist with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm creating a script to create youtube playlist with selenium but I'm stuck here, I've tried many ways but all of them don't work! Can someone help me? thank you

```html
<input type="text" class="Mf-jm-Qc-qb d-Rb" aria-label="Search terms" style="width: 325px;">
```

I tried :

1

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='Mf-jm-Qc-qb d-Rb']").send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NliYy7iqh-U")
```

2

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NliYy7iqh-U")
```

3

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".Mf-jm-Qc-qb").send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NliYy7iqh-U")
```

4

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("Mf-jm-Qc-qb d-Rb").send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NliYy7iqh-U")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element looks to be a *dynamic* element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-label='Search terms'][type='text']"))).send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NliYy7iqh-U")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Search terms' and @type='text']"))).send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NliYy7iqh-U")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried both, but it doesn't work! Here is the picture at this stage https://i.imgur.com/917PMYT.png  @DebanjanB

Comment: @vantuong Possibly the element is within an iframe. If so, switch to the iframe first then lookout for the element.